# Deploying a JApplet: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, wordpress, swing, japplet

Edit 2: I created a html in the root directory and placed the jar file in the same place, I could then get the applet to run (though I had some issues with self-signed security). This tells me the problem is in the applet code. Any ideas why it wouldn't find the class when if I can remove the codebase attribute it runs correctly?

Edit 1: I have updated the entry point to remove the frame. I also tested with the HelloWorld applet and still received the same error.

---

I'm fairly new to Java so I'll try to explain my problem as clearly as I can and with plenty of detail. If I miss anything please let me know. I'm also aware that this problem is frequently asked about on here, I've done a fair bit of research and found conflicting responses and nothing that worked.

I have developed a JApplet in eclipse, exported a jar file for the project and am attempting to deploy it on my website. However, when I attempt to view the applet online I get the error: ClassNotFoundException. It is probably also worth mentioning that I am trying to deploy this JApplet through wordpress.

Here is the html code I'm using to deploy:

```
<applet code = 'gui.ConverterGUI.class' 
    codebase = 'http://www.myurl.co.uk/Java/'
    archive = 'AConverter.jar'
    width = 800
    height = 600>
    <param name="permissions" value="all-permissions" />
</applet>
```

My applet has a few packages and classes which I think I have set up and exported correctly, but incase that is causing problems, here is my main entry point:

```
public class ConverterGUI extends JApplet {
// Current program ver.
public static final double VERSION = 0.0;


public void init() {
    // Make it look nicer.
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}


    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
                SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());

        //JFrame f = new JFrame("Converter GUI");
        ResultDisplay resultDisplay = new ResultDisplay();
        getContentPane().add(resultDisplay, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(new InputFields(resultDisplay), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

[image: My project package set-up]

This is my project layout.

I've exported the jar using Eclipse, I've got the impression that this means it has been signed properly already, but if this is not the case and it is causing issues, I'd appreciate being pointed in the right direction to do this (I do have eclipse set up with the JDK rather than JRE).

Comment: why JApplet with JFrame, because  extends JApplet nnever will be visible, nor initialized

Comment: have to bothering with Official Oracle tutorial about Applets, for working code examples

Comment: I thought that the JFrame would be added to the JApplet, oops. Is there an easy fix for this, or should I simply add the other components directly to the applet?

Comment: @user124784 Add components directly to you JApplet and remove your JFrame inside createAndShowGUI method.

Comment: hmmm you wrote I'm fairly new to Java, then hybrid (is possible without any side problems) application JApplet + JFrame isn't good start point, have to decide if JApplet (embedded to internet explorer) or JFrame (standalone application)

Comment: Ok, I'll clean up so I'm just using a JApplet without the frame and see if that makes it any better. I'll also test with the HelloWorld applet from Oracle (something I really should have done already!)

I just assumed it was fine as I could run it as an applet through eclipse.

Comment: I've tested the HelloWorld demo, and made changes to my code (now in main post). Neither have worked, I still get the same error.

Comment: I guess the problem is from your applet tag. as it is written here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_applet.asp , you should have a double quotation marks on the values in the tag. I am a beginner in HTML, I may be totally wrong.

Comment: I just tried using double quote marks and still the same problem, thanks for the attempt anyway. I'll keep playing around with some stuff D:

Comment: What is a `ResultDisplay`?  What is an `InputFields`?  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: I'm happy to post an example, but I'm having this same issue with a few programs, this is just the most simple I think the issue is in my applet code, jar exporting or what I'm.uploading to the server, can someone verify what these should be please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the html code and the way wordpress was interpreting it. For future reference, I fixed the issue by removing the lines from the html code and using double quotes, as follows:

```
<applet code = "gui.ConverterGUI.class" codebase="http://www.myurl.co.uk/Java/" archive="AConverter.jar" width=800 height=600><param name="permissions" value="all-permissions" /></applet>
```

Nonetheless I did get some useful advice here. Thanks all.